# Converting a div with li elements containing image tags to a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I have markup that looks like this

```
<div class="myDiv"><ul>
<li><img src="img1.jpg"/></li>
<li><img src="img1.jpg"/></li>
.
.
.
</ul></div>
```

I need to convert this html to a slideshow. I am not very good at using javascript or jquery. I just need a something that would enable me to pass the class of the div and then all the images in the lists would be converted to a simple slideshow. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Shouldn't this kind of question usually lead to a quote telling you how much it will cost for someone to develop it for you?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan bruv +1 lolz :) lite joke guys not meant to offend anyone. have a nice one, cheers!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan lol. You are right but everything aint about money

Comment: Of course not, but please at least show some effort in trying to answer your question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiya please try this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/NPcDH/ **||** http://jsfiddle.net/rQS6h/ perhaps **&** further from below comments your personal page demo is here - http://jsfiddle.net/2wnws/2/show/

its a simple slideshow using li rest you can see how it works in jsfiddle. Please let me know if I missed anything.

**html**

```
<div id="slideshow"> 

    <ul>

        <li class="slideshow_item">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/persiannewyear11-hp.jpg" alt="persiannewyear11-hp" /></a> 

        </li>

        <li class="slideshow_item">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/holi11-hp.jpg" alt="holi11-hp" /></a> 

        </li>

        <li class="slideshow_item">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/sayeddarwish11-hp.jpg" alt="sayeddarwish11-hp" /></a> 

        </li>

        <li class="slideshow_item">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/okamoto11-hp.jpg" alt="okamoto11-hp" /></a> 

        </li>

        <li class="slideshow_item">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/eisner11-hp.jpg" alt="eisner11-hp" /></a> 

        </li>

        <li class="slideshow_item">

            <a href="#"><img src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/jfkinaugural11-hp.jpg" alt="jfkinaugural11-hp" /></a> 

        </li>

    </ul> 

</div> ​
```

**Jquery**

```
/* home slide show */

var slide_pos = 0;
var slide_len = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {

    slide_len = $(".slideshow_item").size() - 1;

    $(".slideshow_item:gt(0)").hide();

    slide_int = setInterval(function() {

        slide_cur = $(".slideshow_item:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
        slide_cur.fadeOut(2000);

        slide_pos = (slide_pos == slide_len ? 0 : (slide_pos + 1));

        slide_cur = $(".slideshow_item:eq(" + slide_pos + ")");
        slide_cur.fadeIn(2000);

    }, 5000);

});​
```

**css**

```
#slideshow{

    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;

} #slideshow ul, #slideshow li{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;

} .slideshow_item{

    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    list-style-type:none;

} .slideshow_item img{

    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    vertical-align:bottom;

} ​
```

Comment: Nice answer but the problem is that I have a very unique situation in my own case. I can't apply classes to the lists (unless I use something like myDiv li { } ) so that I means I can't use jquery to select them by class like you did here slide_len = $(".slideshow_item").size() - 1;

Comment: @yankitwizzy Cooleos! how about this one? http://jsfiddle.net/rQS6h/ let me know I will add this as answer as well :) have a good one, cheers!

Comment: Ok so I have tested this your script on my site http://talonsoftwares.com/sweetroof/index.php?option=com_joomd&view=entry&layout=detail&id=1&Itemid=5 but I don't know why the slide is not working. Please could you take a look

Comment: @yankitwizzy okies will do! I am guessing the gallery section is the slide? right, and it seism very first time when page load it does work for first image & is it possible if you can provide jsfidlle that will help me to correct the code and send you right fix? :) else I will read the source of your  page, please lmme know,, cheers!

Comment: Yes the gallery section is the slide. What exactly do you mean by providing you with jsfiddle? Are you using jQuery or Mootools?

Comment: @yankitwizzy hiya no worries, i meant make if you can make this gallery in jsfiddle with issue then I can have full control and I can make the changes Right now I can only see your code through view source (i.e. no control over it) never mind. **AHA** try including later Jquery as well bruv, and see if it works, Cheers

Comment: @yankitwizzy anywho bruv I am taking a look now and will flick you a fiddle, cheers

Comment: @yankitwizzy here you go your page is resolved see sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/2wnws/2/show/ cheers :) **Don't forget to up vote and accept this answer! :)** code: http://jsfiddle.net/2wnws/2/

Comment: Of course I would but pls what exactly did you change in the code?

Comment: @yankitwizzy bruv order of your script was wrong once I sorted that out everything worked fine :) ! like you can see in the fiddle bruv! cheerios http://jsfiddle.net/2wnws/2/show/ **may i recommend** go to the vie source and copy paste to your page that should work, any who you know the stuff :) **&** another recommendation bruv - please don't include so many query library if you aint gonna need it. just an idea. cheerios!!